# Basic DOS terminal browser partition manager?

Tags: system-repair-disc

Last time I met some problems with my hard drive. I found the `Repair your computer` mode, you know, when you press F8 and you have admin rights, you can enter terminal with `SYSTEM` rights. So I can copy all my data to USB, and be very happy... (Yay!!)

But I kept in mind, that to use it on "broken" computers, I need to install Windows (to long, useless, unavailable) or use Windows from USB (to slow, low quality, not 100% sure about working).

So I thought, maybe... there is small chance there exists `Disk Operating System` with tools some basic tools such as (a)browser, (b)partition manager, (c)terminal, (d)editor

a = Not very advanced. I just need for example to download drivers from website if these on computer doesn't work, and need to be reinstalled.
b = Just basic partition manager. Same as `bcdedit.exe` in Windows or atleast most same.
c = Terminal, that can move files, delete them, create them... almost like `command.com` or `cmd.exe`. Just to manage all crap on the disc.
d = I do not mean specific one. Just to read or edit txt, bat, ini, inf etc. files.

Oh I almost forgot! I would be really happy, if "this" would work on newest operating systems, and could work quite fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a [Live CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD):

> A live CD, live DVD, or live disc is a complete bootable computer
>   operating system which runs in the computer's memory, rather than
>   loading from the hard disk drive. It allows users to experience and
>   evaluate an operating system without installing it or making any
>   changes to the existing operating system on the computer. Live CDs are
>   unique because they can run on a computer lacking secondary storage,
>   such as a hard disk drive, or with a corrupted hard disk drive or file
>   system, allowing users to rescue data.

There are tons of ones out there. Here is a [list of linux based ones](http://livecdlist.com/operating-system/linux) and there is a DOS based one called [Doscore](http://livecdlist.com/doscore).

There is also a list [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_live_CDs).